# Counting and ranking the dates based on the number of grid cells when daily rainfall is greater than a threshold in a netcdf file using Python

Tags: python-3.x, netcdf, python-xarray

I have daily gridded rainfall data with **dimensions (time: 14245, lon: 40, lat: 20)**  . I've calculated 2,3,5 and 7-days accumulated rainfall and their respective 90th percentiles at every grid points in my data domain. I've set my condition using **DataArray.where(condition, drop=True)** to know when daily rainfall amount exceed the threshold as shown in the code below. My current working code is here:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

#=== reading in the data ===
data_path = '/home/wilson/Documents/PH_D/GPCC/GPCC/GPCC_daily_1982-2020.nc'
data = xr.open_dataset(data_path)

#=== computing 2, 3, 5 and 7-days acummulated rainfall amount ===
data[['precip_2d']] = np.around(data.precip.rolling(time=2).sum(),decimals=2)
data[['precip_3d']] = np.around(data.precip.rolling(time=3).sum(),decimals=2)
data[['precip_5d']] = np.around(data.precip.rolling(time=5).sum(),decimals=2)
data[['precip_7d']] = np.around(data.precip.rolling(time=7).sum(),decimals=2)

#=== Computing 10% largest at each grid point (per grid cel) this is 90th percentile ===

data[['accum_2d_90p']] = np.around(data.precip_2d.quantile(0.9, dim='time'), decimals=2)
data[['accum_3d_90p']] = np.around(data.precip_3d.quantile(0.9, dim='time'), decimals=2)
data[['accum_5d_90p']] = np.around(data.precip_5d.quantile(0.9, dim='time'), decimals=2)
data[['accum_7d_90p']] = np.around(data.precip_7d.quantile(0.9, dim='time'), decimals=2)

#=== locating extreme events, i.e., when daily precip greater than 90th percentile of each of the accumulated rainfall amount ===
data[['extreme_2d']] = data['precip'].where(data['precip'] > data['accum_2d_90p'], drop=True)
data[['extreme_3d']] = data['precip'].where(data['precip'] > data['accum_2d_90p'], drop=True)
data[['extreme_5d']] = data['precip'].where(data['precip'] > data['accum_2d_90p'], drop=True)
data[['extreme_7d']] = data['precip'].where(data['precip'] > data['accum_2d_90p'], drop=True)
```

My problem now is how to count the number of grid cells/points within my domain where the condition is true on a particular date and using the result of the count to rank the date in descending order.
Expected result should look like a table that can be saved as txt file. For example: cells_count is a variable that contain desired result, when print(cells_count) gives

| Date | Number of grid cells/point |
| --- | --- |
| 1992-07-01 | 432 |
| 1983-09-23 | 407 |
| 2009-08-12 | 388 |

Comment: DataArray.where will return a nan when the condition is false - not sure how you’re getting zeros. But the result is the same shape as your original array. Passing drop=True can only drop elements along a given coordinate if all of the values can be dropped, otherwise you could lose data. Can you give an example of what exactly you’re hoping to see as a result? As far as I can tell, it’s currently doing exactly what you’re describing.

Comment: Thank you Micheal for the comments. I've been thinking about it and how it could be possible. What am expecting to see in the results should be the only date where the condition I've set is true. My thinking now is that this condition will not be true at every grid points over my domain, there the **time dimension** will vary significantly from one grid point to another. I don't want my result to contain the dates where my condition is false.

Comment: Yeah so the dimensions of an array can’t vary from pixel to pixel, so this isn’t possible as you describe. I think you’ll need to keep thinking through exactly what you’re trying to achieve. What do you want to do with this?

Comment: What I want to do is to select the dates of those events that affect the largest number of contiguous (next to each other) grid cells. That is, the date when the daily rainfall amount exceeds the 90th percentile.

Comment: yeah I understand that - I mean what's the larger goal? xarray does not support  [jagged arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array), which have the lengths of some dimensions varying along one or more other dimensions. is your goal really just to have a giant, jagged array of dates or are you hoping to do something with them? Wondering if what you're trying to do can be done using the mask with NaNs, e.g. `data['precip'].where(data['precip'] > data['accum_2d_90p'])` or even `data['precip'].time.where(data['precip'] > data['accum_2d_90p'])`.

Comment: I want to select few extreme events case (especially events that covers larger grid cells ) and diagnose the environmental condition leading to the occurrence of such events

Comment: I would do that by identifying the reduction you want over grid cells first, and then masking the dates that have the global property you want. For example, `data['precip'].time.where((data['precip'] > data['accum_2d_90p']).mean(dim=("lat", "lon")) > 0.5)` <-- this will return the dates on which more than half the world is experiencing a 90%ile day. much easier to work with than a jagged 3D array of dates :)

Comment: Thank you. I will try it and verify the results and let you know.

Comment: Once again thank you for the help Micheal. I tried your suggestion but did not give me result. After thinking a lot, I think what I need to do is to sort the dates in descending order based on the number of grid cells that satisfied my condition over my domain simultaneously (i.e., I will like to count all the grid cells that satisfied my condition as stated above and the use the result of the count to rank the date). Thereafter I can begin to work with these dates.

Comment: I've also edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok based on your comments it sounds like what you'd like is to get a list of dates in your `time` coordinate based on a global summary statistic of 3D (time, lat, lon) data. I'll use the condition `(data['precip'] > data['accum_2d_90p'])` as an example.

I'd definitely recommend reducing the dimensionality of your condition first, before working with the dates, because working with ragged 3D datetime arrays is a real pain. So since you mention wanting the count of pixels satisfying the criteria, you can simply do this:

```py
global_pixel_count = (
    (data['precip'] > data['accum_2d_90p']).sum(dim=("lat", "lon"))
)
```

Now, you have a 1-D array, `global_pixel_count`, indexed by `time` only. You can get the ranked order of dates from this using [`xr.DataArray.argsort`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.argsort.html):

```py
sorted_date_positions = global_pixel_count.argsort()
sorted_dates = global_pixel_count.time.isel(
    time=sorted_date_positions.values
)
```

This will return a DataArray of dates which sort the array in *ascending* order. You could reverse this to get the dates in descending order with `sorted_date_positions.values[::-1]` and you could select all the pixel counts in descending order with:

```py
global_pixel_count.isel(time=sorted_date_positions.values[::-1])
```

you could also index your entire array with this indexer:

```py
data.isel(time=sorted_date_positions.values[::-1])
```